# Need to include variables in Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am fetching an xml from a text file using following Regex pattern in Selenium using Java

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<\\?xml.*\\?>(.+?)</a>");
```

But in this case it is not fetching the particular XML I want from the text file. There is an unique identifier ( order id ) which i want to pass in this Regex pattern

```
<order_id>D668724063</order_id>
```

for fetching the particular XML i want.

I am storing this order id in a variable "orderid" and i want to pass this in the Regex pattern . Can somebody please help me out with this  ?
[Sample text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF4JL.png)

Comment: *I am fetching an xml from a text file using following Regex pattern...*  Stop right there.  Do not try to parse XML with regular expressions.  [**Use an XML parser**.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm)

Comment: Thanks kjhughes for the response but I am fetching the required XML from a large text file ( 15-20 MB) which will have a lot XML files and only unique identifier is the order id. After fetching the XML containing the order id , I have to go through the child nodes of the fetched XML to get the required details. Can you guide me as how this can be done using XML parser ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?  Not too large, just a few XML documents, maybe a few hundred characters each.  Edit your question to add the sample, with appropriate code formatting.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your response . I have added the attachment of a sample file where there are many XMLs and i have to fetch the entire XML based on the order id and then go through the child nodes of the fetched XML to get the required card details

Comment: I was thinking of something in text form, that we can cut and paste into our tool of choice to test our solutions.  The less grunt work we have to do, the more answers you're likely to get.

Comment: I'm glad that you've scrubbed the credit card data in your file, but assuming you're program is for real data, I don't think that you should be writing this program. Your program appears to be a violation of Payment Card Industry regulation (i.e. dos and don'ts of credit card data). Read up on it at: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf Basically the issue is that you're reading unencrypted credit card numbers and 3/4 digit CVV numbers from a file, which means that you're storing it somewhere, which is a big no-no as you can see from that link.